# What's the difference between GA pageview and screenview?

Tags: google-analytics

I was wondering what's the difference between `pageview` and `screenview`.

This [GA library](https://github.com/ScreamZ/vue-analytics/blob/45c3a05e3c/src/AnalyticsPlugin.js)  **vue-analytics** 's `trackView` methods use `screenview`.

That's confusing to me.

And I have seen people track `pageview` and `screenview` at the same time(each route will send these two)

So what's the difference between these two?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Screenview` in Google Analytics represent content users are viewing within an app. The equivalent concept for a website is `pageview`. Measuring screen views allows you to see which content is being viewed most by your users, and how are they are navigating between different pieces of content.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/screens

Until some time ago there was a dedicated Property for app interactions, where to send the `screenview` and which had slightly different reports from the Property for the web. This Property has been deprecated. Now the apps use **Firebase** Analytics:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics

To get web and mobile app interactions there is a new Analytics Property based on a new data model, which is called: **App + Web**:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165?hl=en
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/app-web/tag-guide

Comment: So... when talking about a website, screenviews and pageviews are the same?

Comment: Pageviews for a website